# How to fix this error (Bukkit, Iterator, Arraylists...error)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to collect all players in the Arraylist with this (This is spigot 1.16.5):

Arraylist constructor: `public static ArrayList<Player> playerInGame = new ArrayList<>();`

```
public void makePlayerWin(Player perdente) {
        Iterator<Player> it = playerInGame.iterator();
        if(!it.hasNext()) return;
        Player players = it.next();
        System.out.println(1);
        if(playerInGame.contains(perdente) && players.getWorld() == Bukkit.getWorld(plugin.Game) || playerInGame.contains(perdente) && !perdente.isOnline()) {
            System.out.println(2);
            playerInGame.remove(perdente);
            LobbyJoin(players);
            players.sendTitle(plugin.cc("&6Hai vinto!"), plugin.cc("&7Sei tornato alla lobby!"));
            playerInGame.remove(players);
        }
    }
```

But I get this error:

[image: Error in console]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Arraylist is not threadsafe. You can make the  arraylist to synronized list with Collections.syncronizedList()

Comment: @OlgunYILDIZ like this?

 Iterator<Player> it = Collections.synchronizedList(playerInGame).iterator();

Comment: Synchronizing the array list won't solve the concurrent modification exception, because the problem is hanging on to an open iterator while the list is being modified. Synchronization over individual calls to the list won't fix this!

Comment: @JoachimSauer and, with this, what can i do?

Comment: The code for `onQuit` isn't shown. I suspect that method marches through the list, while the method `makePlayerWin` also executes. If they execute on different threads, the solution would be using a lock while iterating, in both methods. If, on the other hand, `onQuit` calls `makePlayerWin`, you'd need another solution.